# Create new column with dplyr mutate and substring of existing column

Tags: r, dplyr, strsplit

I have a dataframe with a column of strings and want to extract substrings of those into a new column.

Here is some sample code and data showing I want to take the string after the final underscore character in the `id` column in order to create a `new_id` column.
The `id` column entry always has 2 underscore characters and it's always the final substring I would like.

```
df = data.frame( id = I(c("abcd_123_ABC","abc_5234_NHYK")), x = c(1.0,2.0) )

require(dplyr)

df = df %>% dplyr::mutate(new_id = strsplit(id, split="_")[[1]][3])
```

I was expecting strsplit to act on each row in turn.

However, the `new_id` column only contains `ABC` in each row, whereas I would like `ABC` in row 1 and `NHYK` in row 2. Do you know why this fails and how to achieve what I want?

Comment: it's because of your call to `strsplit`.  the `[[1]]` always grabs the first element of the list.

Comment: in base R, its as simple as a little regex magic: `df$newVar <- sub(".*_([A-Z]+)$", "\\1", df$id)`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could use `stringr::str_extract`:

```
library(stringr)

 df %>%
   dplyr::mutate(new_id = str_extract(id, "[^_]+$"))


#>              id x new_id
#> 1  abcd_123_ABC 1    ABC
#> 2 abc_5234_NHYK 2   NHYK
```

The regex says, match one or more (`+`) of the characters that *aren't* `_` (the negating `[^ ]`), followed by end of string (`$`).

Answer (score 32):

An alternative without regex and keeping in the `tidyverse` style is to use `tidyr::separate()`. Note, this does remove the input column by default (`remove=FALSE` to prevent it).

```
## using your example data
df = data.frame( id = I(c("abcd_123_ABC","abc_5234_NHYK")), x = c(1.0,2.0) )

## separate knowing you will have three components
df %>% separate(id, c("first", "second", "new_id"), sep = "_") %>% select(-first, -second)
## returns
  new_id x
1    ABC 1
2   NHYK 2
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `dplyr::rowwise`:

```
df %>% dplyr::rowwise() %>% dplyr::mutate(new_id = strsplit(id, split="_")[[1]][3])
```

Further alternatives are discussed here:

http://www.expressivecode.org/2014/12/17/mutating-using-functions-in-dplyr/

Comment: Note that this will be slower than typical `dplyr` as it can't benefit from vectorized operations. Still, +1 for the tip.

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using `str_split` by specifying the `simplify` argument.

Simplify unlists the split strings and allows element selection using an index. In this case where there is always 2x "_", we can always take the third element.

```
# Create df
df = data.frame( id = I(c("abcd_123_ABC","abc_5234_NHYK")), x = c(1.0,2.0) )

# Create new_id using dplyr only
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(new_id = str_split(id, "_", simplify = TRUE)[ , 3])
```

See https://github.com/tidyverse/stringr/issues/265

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to use `strsplit` in a general way to do what you're looking for.

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame( id = I(c("abcd_123_ABC","abc_5234_NHYK")), x = c(1.0,2.0) )

temp <- seq(from=3, by=3, length.out = length(df))
dfn <- df %>% dplyr::mutate(new_id = unlist(strsplit(id, split="_"))[temp])

> dfn
             id x new_id
1  abcd_123_ABC 1    ABC
2 abc_5234_NHYK 2   NHYK
```